# Assigning permission to user using workflow (sharepoint 2010)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm using *Replace* to assign permission to user on a library using workflow, then in another workflow I'm again using *Replace* to assign permission to different user on same library. Now it's replacing permissions assigned by first workflow and I want both permissions. Any idea why this happens, and how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It happens due to you using "Replace List Item Permisssions" which will replace all existing permissions:
[image]
So it's not replacing the permissions of the specified uses with the one specified and leaving other users permissions. It is deleting all permissions for everybody and the adding the ones specified.

If you want to add permissions you should use "Add List Item Permissions":
[image]